# java webapplication profiling with JProfiler (7.0.1) & Execution time review

Tags: java, web-applications, profiling, jprofiler

any one can help me setup a java **web-application** profiling with the **JProfiler(7.0.1).**
I have searching on net but i have found only for the application that contain `main calss` in it.
give me any link or doc that give step-by-step idea for setting profiling with java web-application.

**Edited**
Thanks all for your reply..
i have successfully integrate JProfiler with my application..
But i have not find any execution time description for the particular method can anyone know how to see the execution time for the request or any method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to configure a standalone server for profiling (whether running locally or remotely) is by invoking

Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration

from JProfiler's main menu. In the integration wizard you can select your server and then you follow the steps in the integration wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get a look at this, you'll find all the explanations about profiling a webapp:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/profiling/remote.html

Answer (score 1):

***You should create a new question for your "edited" part.***
However, I'll try to answer it here:

If you really need the execution times, you must profile in "instrumentation mode" (which will slow down profiling significantly)
But in the most cases, a percentage value (sampling mode, CPU Call Tree/Hotspots) is enough for finding the bottleneck.